# Capturing Dos Window Progress

Tags: windows, delphi, winapi, delphi-xe2, delphi-xe

I am using the code at the end of my question for capturing outputs of dos applications.

I trying to capture output of the 7z.exe command below:

**7z.exe  x -y "C:\Linux.iso" -o"E:\"**

7z.exe is showing a progress at the end of its dos window like %14.., %15..., %16... But it is not adding new lines for each progress. It is updating the last line of the dos output window. So the last line of the dos window changes like %14.., %15.., .. and 100%.

I am unable to capture this %14.., %15, %16.. progress. I am trying to find a solution for days. How can I capture this progress texts?

--

Note: The code is working and capturing the output great with the commands like ping:

ping 127.0.0.1

The problem is capturing the dos window's output which is not adding a new line, updating a line.

```
// Source: https://thundaxsoftware.blogspot.com/2012/12/capturing-console-output-with-delphi.html#comment-form_7827048960744956444
//
// @Author: Jordi Corbilla
// (c) Copyright by Jordi Corbilla.
// Anonymous procedure approach by Lars Fosdal

type
    TArg<T> = reference to procedure(const Arg: T);

procedure TForm1.CaptureConsoleOutput(const ACommand, AParameters: String; CallBack: TArg<PAnsiChar>);
const
  CReadBuffer = 2400;
var
  saSecurity: TSecurityAttributes;
  hRead: THandle;
  hWrite: THandle;
  suiStartup: TStartupInfo;
  piProcess: TProcessInformation;
  pBuffer: array [0 .. CReadBuffer] of AnsiChar;
  dBuffer: array [0 .. CReadBuffer] of AnsiChar;
  dRead: DWORD;
  dRunning: DWORD;
  dAvailable: DWORD;
begin
  saSecurity.nLength := SizeOf(TSecurityAttributes);
  saSecurity.bInheritHandle := true;
  saSecurity.lpSecurityDescriptor := nil;
  if CreatePipe(hRead, hWrite, @saSecurity, 0) then
    try
      FillChar(suiStartup, SizeOf(TStartupInfo), #0);
      suiStartup.cb := SizeOf(TStartupInfo);
      suiStartup.hStdInput := hRead;
      suiStartup.hStdOutput := hWrite;
      suiStartup.hStdError := hWrite;
      suiStartup.dwFlags := STARTF_USESTDHANDLES or STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW;
      suiStartup.wShowWindow := SW_HIDE;
      if CreateProcess(nil, PChar(ACommand + ' ' + AParameters), @saSecurity, @saSecurity, true, NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS, nil, nil, suiStartup,
        piProcess) then
        try
          repeat
            dRunning := WaitForSingleObject(piProcess.hProcess, 100);
            PeekNamedPipe(hRead, nil, 0, nil, @dAvailable, nil);
            if (dAvailable > 0) then
              repeat
                dRead := 0;
                ReadFile(hRead, pBuffer[0], CReadBuffer, dRead, nil);
                pBuffer[dRead] := #0;
                OemToCharA(pBuffer, dBuffer);
                CallBack(dBuffer);
              until (dRead < CReadBuffer);
            Application.ProcessMessages;
          until (dRunning <> WAIT_TIMEOUT);
        finally
          CloseHandle(piProcess.hProcess);
          CloseHandle(piProcess.hThread);
        end;
    finally
      CloseHandle(hRead);
      CloseHandle(hWrite);
    end;
end;
```

Comment: Surely it would be better to use a 7zip library rather than an external process?

Comment: You are so right, I should use 7z.dll for this process. Thank you very much for the idea. The thing I want to ask, is it possible to integrate 7z.dll in the exe file. So that I can do the job without 7z.dll.

Comment: Does [this](http://www.drbob42.com/delphi/headconv.htm) help you at all?  I only skimmed it but it looks promising.  I would not seek to do anything other than bundle 7z.dll with your app and call into it to have it do the things you want it to do.

Comment: _"integrate 7z.dll in the exe file"_ -- I'm not a delphi expect, but in general you could store the DLL in resource section of executable. When the executable runs, extract DLL to temporary directory and load it. Alternatively generate a self-extracting archive that includes your EXE and 7z.dll.

Comment: Ship exe and dll

Comment: 1) I have added 7z.dll to the exe resource (Project -> Resources and Images)

2) I integrated [7zip delphi](https://github.com/zedalaye/d7zip) pas and [BTMemoryModule](https://github.com/jasonpenny/democode/tree/master/dGinaTest/). (One useful [link](https://www.thoughtco.com/load-a-dll-from-a-resource-1058456))

dll got successfully loaded from memory and it worked. Thank you everyone.

Comment: How I integrated 7zip delphi pas and BTMemoryModule: I only modified 7zip delphi pas. There was 2 dll referenced methods in the pas and I changed them as variable. I used BTMemoryLoadLibary at unit initialization, BTMemoryFreeLibrary at finalization and replaced LoadLibrary methods with BTMemoryGetProcAddress. I removed FreeLibrary methods and dll name variables.